# how do i use the result of a function for an insert statement?

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert

I have a function that returns a varchar

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE Function HashPassword(in p_email varchar, in p_password varchar)
RETURNS TABLE(
    o_password varchar,
    o_user_id int
) as
$$
    return query select 'myresult', 9999;
END
$$
Language plpgsql;
```

I want to do an insert into a table that is the result of the function call

```
insert into table_that_needs_it(id, password, date)
select 99999, (select o_password from HashPassword('myemail', 'mypassword')), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

It's giving me the following error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use only a single SELECT:

```
insert into table_that_needs_it(id, password, date)
select 99999, o_password, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
from hashpassword('myemail', 'mypassword');
```

If you also want to use the ID:

```
insert into table_that_needs_it(id, password, date)
select o_user_id, o_password, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
from hashpassword('myemail', 'mypassword');
```

Comment: oh man, i can't believe i missed that. thanks worked perfectly